# Who is the (contemporary) photographer using an old bellows camera?

Tags: history, professional, bellows

I have read about a photographer (possibly working for/collaborating with the National Geographic society) who was using (not uniquely, of course) an old style bellows camera for his shoots. He went on to comment that this archaic instrument gave him, as I am sure one could expect, a rather unique feeling when shooting.

I have also a vague recollection that he may have done some portrait works for famous people (think US politicians).

This has been fascinating me, but unfortunately I have been unable to find his name again. I am reasonably sure not to have imagined it all. Maybe someone recalls the name, or even knows him directly :-), or at least can give me some pointers...

Comment: To be fair, you can use a digital camera with bellows - bellows do not imply film (companies like Sinar make digital cameras with bellows...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's David Burnett, he was recently seen photographing the 2012 London Olympics with his Graflex Speed Graphic

http://www.lomography.com/magazine/lifestyle/2012/08/09/david-burnett-an-analogue-view-of-the-olympics

Here's a great video of him going through his bag and talking about his gear:
https://vimeo.com/13036394

Comment: Nice one. Head on over to Francesco's other question and answer there too! http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26678/help-identifying-a-camera-during-the-london-olympics-games-2012

Comment: Already way ahead of you :)

Comment: In Italy we say "prendere due piccioni con una fava" (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendere_due_piccioni_con_una_fava). Thanks @camflan.

Comment: I did remember correctly http://www.davidburnett.com/fmsetgallery.html?loopTrack=1&folio=Galleries&gallery=The%20Presidents%20