# Help identifying a camera during the London Olympics games 2012

Tags: medium-format, large-format, bellows, camera-identification, olympics2012

During the final competition of the individual all-around gymnastics (won by [Gabby Douglas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabby_Douglas)) I noticed a photographer (if memory doesn't fail me, he was placed behind the russian team) with a very large and "strange looking" camera.

Did anybody else see him? What camera was it? Was it simply a large format? Was it an old bellows camera? From what I cannot remember it did seem relatively old but maybe large or medium format camera are like that and I simply cannot recognize one :-)

I have searched on youtube but obviously all the focus is on the performances of the athletes and **not** on all the great camera gear that was floating around the venues, can you believe that? ;-)

P.S.: the reference to old bellows camera is of course related to [this other](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26677/5032) question of mine.

Comment: Some people had stereo/ 3D camera equipment, which may be what you saw.

Comment: I am sure that he inserted and removed slides from the side of the camera : if memory serves me from his right side (so it was on the left of the tv screen).

Comment: Btw: great, there are 3d cameras around and all those youtube clips instead focus on gymnastics (which unfortunately I am not interested in, I just happened to watch the contest while working at home)... :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are talking about the 4x5 Graflex Speed Graphic that David Burnett was shooting with.

http://www.lomography.com/magazine/lifestyle/2012/08/09/david-burnett-an-analogue-view-of-the-olympics

Comment: One little nit to pick: the Speed Graphic is a 4x5 sheet film camera, not medium format. You can use a medium format roll film holder with the Graflex back, but the "real deal" is to use a 6-sheet Grafmatic holder.

Comment: @StanRogers you are quite right, my mistake. I've edited it to reflect this.

Comment: And four years later, *I* own a speed graphic in good working order :-)

Answer (score 3):

At a distance [**this dual camera arrangement**](http://www.computerworld.com.au/slideshow/431497/getty_images_focuses_3d_cameras_olympics/?image=1) from [**here**](http://www.computerworld.com.au/article/431497/getty_images_focuses_3d_cameras_olympics/#closeme) used by Getty Images to capture 3D footage may have looked large and/or strange.

The article talks about a single system but seems to also include  footage without any real discussion of a robotic camera which appears far closer to what you described. This appears to be a 35mm DSLR (probably 5D MkIII well encased in robot armour -

[image]

Probably not a temporarily down to earth [Skycam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skycam) but worth a mention.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the pic but the camera was being operated on a tripod and it definitely didn't have such a regular looking lens. At first sight it really appeared to my eyes as a black box like an old style camera...